# Calculate as.duration - and ignore NA columns

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the duration between column 'vasopressor on' and 'vasopressor off' - these columns have been created by finding the min and max values in specified columns.

The data set contains rows of NA - they need to remain NA in the newly created column vasopressor duration or be converted to 0

When I run my code on a simplified data set it works. When I apply it to my dataset I get all the newly created columns filled with NA. However when I omit the last line of code for vasopressor duration the other 2 columns vasopressor_on and vasopressor_off fill with values

I have attached a reproducible example code followed by my `dput()`:

```
study_ID <- c(5,6,7)
randomisation <- (c("2021-01-01 11:00", NA, "2021-01-03 10:00"))
water_on <- (c("2021-01-01 13:00", NA,"2021-01-04 09:45"))
water_off <- (c("2021-01-01 18:00", NA,"2021-01-04 11:00"))
trial_A <- data.frame(study_ID, randomisation, water_on, water_off)

trial_A_1 <- trial_A  %>% dplyr::mutate(across(c(randomisation, water_on, water_off), ymd_hm))

robustmax <- function(x) {if (length(x)>0) max(x) else -Inf} 
robustmin <- function(x) {if (length(x)>0) min(x) else Inf}

Primary <- trial_A_1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_on = robustmin(c_across(c(randomisation, water_on, water_off)))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_off = robustmax(c_across(c(randomisation, water_on, water_off)))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_duration = (vasopressor_on %--% vasopressor_off) %>% as.duration() / dhours()) %>% ungroup()

# My code applied to my data 

Primary <- test_df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_on = robustmin(c_across(c(true_adrenaline_on, true_noradrenaline_on, true_vasopressin_on,true_phenylephrine_on,true_metaraminol_on)))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_off = robustmax(c_across(c(true_adrenaline_off, true_noradrenaline_off, true_vasopressin_off,true_phenylephrine_off,true_metaraminol_off)))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_duration = (vasopressor_on %--% vasopressor_off) %>% as.duration() / dhours()) %>% ungroup()

test_ df <- data.frame(
  true_adrenaline_on = as.POSIXct(
    rep(c("2020-08-31 13:05:00", NA, "2020-09-17 20:58:00", NA), c(1L, 3L, 1L, 5L)),
    tz = "UTC"
  ),
  true_noradrenaline_on = as.POSIXct(
    c(
      "2020-08-31 13:05:00", "2020-09-03 14:00:00", NA, "2020-09-17 16:00:00",
      "2020-09-17 23:00:00", NA, "2020-09-21 14:10:00", "2020-09-24 14:17:00",
      NA, "2020-09-28 14:20:00"
    ),
    tz = "UTC"
  ),
  true_vasopressin_on = as.POSIXct(
    rep(c(NA, "2020-09-18 09:00:00", NA, "2020-09-28 19:00:00"), rep(c(4L, 1L), 2)),
    tz = "UTC"
  ),
  true_phenylephrine_on = as.POSIXct(rep(NA_character_, 10L), tz = "UTC"),
  true_metaraminol_on = as.POSIXct(rep(NA_character_, 10L), tz = "UTC"),
  true_adrenaline_off = as.POSIXct(
    rep(c("2020-09-01 08:00:00", NA, "2020-09-18 09:00:00", NA), c(1L, 3L, 1L, 5L)),
    tz = "UTC"
  ),
  true_noradrenaline_off = as.POSIXct(
    c(
      "2020-09-01 06:00:00", "2020-09-04 22:00:00", NA, "2020-09-17 18:00:00",
      "2020-09-21 07:00:00", NA, "2020-09-21 22:00:00", "2020-09-25 00:00:00",
      NA, "2020-09-29 16:00:00"
    ),
    tz = "UTC"
  ),
  true_vasopressin_off = as.POSIXct(
    rep(c(NA, "2020-09-21 07:00:00", NA, "2020-09-29 04:00:00"), rep(c(4L, 1L), 2)),
    tz = "UTC"
  ),
  true_phenylephrine_off = as.POSIXct(rep(NA_character_, 10L), tz = "UTC"),
  true_metaraminol_off = as.POSIXct(rep(NA_character_, 10L), tz = "UTC")
)
```

Comment: Can you add to your codeblock the package that `robustmin()` and `robustmax()` belong to? Is it `concurve`, `robustETM`, or something else? Thanks

Comment: Apologies robustmin() and robustmax() apply to a function that didn't get copied accross. Post updated @LeroyTyrone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with `pmin()`, `pmax()`, and `difftime()`

```
test_df |> 
  mutate(
    vasopressor_on = pmin(true_adrenaline_on, true_noradrenaline_on, true_vasopressin_on,true_phenylephrine_on,true_metaraminol_on, na.rm=T),
    vasopressor_off = pmax(true_adrenaline_off, true_noradrenaline_off, true_vasopressin_off,true_phenylephrine_off,true_metaraminol_off, na.rm=T)
  ) |> 
  mutate(vasopressor_duration = difftime(vasopressor_off, vasopressor_on, units='hours') |> as.numeric()) |>
  select(vasopressor_on, vasopressor_off, vasopressor_duration)
```

Note that the unit of duration is `hours`.

**output**

```
         vasopressor_on     vasopressor_off vasopressor_duration
1  2020-08-31 13:05:00 2020-09-01 08:00:00            18.916667
2  2020-09-03 14:00:00 2020-09-04 22:00:00            32.000000
3                 <NA>                <NA>                   NA
4  2020-09-17 16:00:00 2020-09-17 18:00:00             2.000000
5  2020-09-17 20:58:00 2020-09-21 07:00:00            82.033333
6                 <NA>                <NA>                   NA
7  2020-09-21 14:10:00 2020-09-21 22:00:00             7.833333
8  2020-09-24 14:17:00 2020-09-25 00:00:00             9.716667
9                 <NA>                <NA>                   NA
10 2020-09-28 14:20:00 2020-09-29 16:00:00            25.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `time_diff()` from my package `timeplyr`.

It utilises lubridate `intervals` and `durations` to calculate time differences.

It also supports period calculations too.

## Example code

```
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
trial_A_1 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_duration = time_diff(vasopressor_on, vasopressor_off, by = "hours"))
```

Answer (score 0):

trial_A_1%>%
dplyr::mutate(
vasopressor_on = pmin(true_adrenaline_on, true_noradrenaline_on, true_vasopressin_on,true_phenylephrine_on,true_metaraminol_on, na.rm=TRUE),
vasopressor_off = pmax(true_adrenaline_off, true_noradrenaline_off, true_vasopressin_off,true_phenylephrine_off,true_metaraminol_off, na.rm=TRUE)
) %>% dplyr::mutate(vasopressor_duration = vasopressor_on %--% vasopressor_off %/% dhours(1)) %>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(vasopressor_duration), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))

Thank you for everyones input. Above is the final solution I went with. I think the error in my code was that I wrote as.duration as opposed to %/% dhours(1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).